# Quiero abrir un video desde mi escritorio con python

Tags: python

Utilizo este código pero me marca acceso denegado.
lo que yo quiero hacer es que desde la interfaz que cree yo misma pueda abrir un video y reproducirlo de dicha interfaz

```
import os
from tkinter import *

app = Tk()
app.title('Video Player')

Fcanvas = Canvas(bg="black", height=600, width=170)


def snd1():
    os.system("/Users/niet/Desktop/sinsajo.mp4")

var = IntVar()

rb1 = Radiobutton(app, text= "Play Video", variable = var, value=1, command=snd1)
rb1.pack(anchor = W)
Fcanvas.pack()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hola aryan, solo por aclarar un poco el tema, lo que este código pretende es abrir el vídeo en el reproductor determinado del sistema (VLC, WMP, etc). Si lo que quieres es reproducirlo en la misma GUI de tkinter la cosa es mucho mas complicada. Supongo que es posible pero se requieren librerías externas y no es algo trivial. Otros Frameworks traen reproductores básicos integrados como Kivy o Qt (PyQt), en Tkinter no existe esto.

Comment: ok gracias y si quiero abrir el video y que se reprodusca en la gui que estoy haciendo